# print students from a particular year using user input

Tags: python

```
x = input("Enter a Filename: ")
try:
    o = open(x, "r")
    p = o.read()
    y = tuple(j.split() for j in p.splitlines())
    for v1,v2,v3,fname,*rest_of_name in y:
        print("{:<30} {:<10} {:<5} {:<5}".format(' '.join(rest_of_name) + ',' + fname, v1,v3, v2))
    b = int(input("Enter a year: "))
    if b == int(v2):
        print("{:<30} {:<10} {:<5} {:<5}".format(' '.join(rest_of_name) + ',' + fname, v1,v3, v2))

    o.close()
except IOError as e :
    print("File Does Not Exist")
```

Basically my code here imports a file of students and formats the layout so they are all neatly aligned in columns of name,regnum,degreescheme,year which is shown below

```
Simpson,Bart                   12345      G400  2    
Simpson,Lisa                   12346      GH46  1    
J Simpson,Homer                12347      G401  2    
Grainger,Hermione              12348      H610  4    
Potter,Harry                   12349      G400  3    
Shmoikel Krustofski,Herschel   12350      G402  1
```

However, now i'm try to ask the user to input a year for example "2" and this should then only print:

```
Simpson,Bart                   12345      G400  2
J Simpson,Homer                12347      G401  2
```

Comment: I tried creating a variable called a = input("enter a year") then when entered it would print the students in that particular year

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
print re.findall(r"^.*[ ]"+str(x)+"[ ]*$,p)
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iY3eK8/7

Or

```
import re
print [k for k in p.splitlines() if re.split(r" {2,}",k)[3]==str(x)]
```

Comment: thats a bit too complex for me

Comment: it wasn't me that downvoted you btw, and I'm pretty sure there is a much simpler way to do it

Comment: it says invalid syntax for the new one

Comment: i tried the code above and it just outputs [], the one you put up it said index out of range

Comment: @mdbuzz you have used `{1` instead of `{2` and `k2` instead of `k3`

Comment: yeah because it gives me an error that says list index out of range

Comment: I would have liked something like the code above but nothing outputs event though I say print the students that are equal to the users input

Answer (score 0):

```
x = input("Enter a Filename: ")
try:
    o = open(x, "r")
    p = o.read()
    y = tuple(j.split() for j in p.splitlines())
    for v1, v2, v3, fname, *rest_of_name in y:
            print ("{:<30} {:<10} {:<5} {:<5}.format(''.join(rest_of_name)) + ',' + fname, v1, v3, v2")
    year = input("Enter a year:")
    for v1, v2, v3, fname, *rest_of_name in y:
        if v2 == year:
            print ("{:<30} {:<10} {:<5} {:<5}.format(''.join(rest_of_name)) + ',' + fname, v1, v3, v2")
    o.close()
except IOError as e:
    print ("File Does Not Exist")
```

Comment: The first part works how it prints out all the students, but after that I wanted to prompt the user "enter a year to see which students are in that year" then it would output the students in that particular year

Comment: I change my answer, did you mean like that? But i think use `re` is a more advance solution.